# c# Main form loader does not seem to work after dropbox sync problems

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

please mind I'm still a beginner:

I am creating a program with windows forms in c#. However, after i had some sync issues the main form loader does not seam to be working. I checked the code with my limited knowledge but i can't seem to find anything wrong?

Here's the code (mainfrm.designer.cs:1):

```
...
this.Name = "frm_Main";
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frm_Main_Load);
this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
...
```

And here is my loader (mainfrm.cs)

```
private void frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Everything i do here does not get executed.
}
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on `frm_Main_Load`?  Based on what you have shown above, this definitely should be executed when the form loads.  Bear in mind that the `Load` event only occurs once, and when the form was loaded and not when it is opened or displayed.

Comment: No breakpoints, However it seems my code does seem to get executed at
        public frm_Main()
        {
        } ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034

Comment: Ha yes, you are right! It only happened recently so it must be a update that ran. It works fine if i just run the application without the debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug within Visual Studio, as mentioned by Hans.
[stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034)